# REST API request, winform

Tags: c#, winforms, api, request

> Hello to everyone!

I am working on project that is client program( WinForm ). When i create new form for new functionality, i need to make `a lot of requests to API`. For instance i need get statuses to show on form, get data for grid view, check some users data, and so on!

`So, question is`: Is it ok to have more than 1 request to API, when i load form?
If not how to decrease number of request? or may be i need new method to API, that will return all that data? Thanks!

Comment: you can populate your objects and send them over with one request to API.

Comment: What you mean? You mean create new method in API, that will encapsulate all functionality for that form? Give an example, please!

Answer (score 0):

It is not a best solution that u can make more request to api in form load. You try to write override methods to api if it is open source. so that you can reduce more calls. Learn the api completely about its functionality. If you need more precise answer please post the code or samples which might help you to get what exactly you want.